# Automatically adjust pricing to factor in Stripe processing fees

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

I have a website in which I use Stripe and its NodeJS SDK. In particular, I use the checkout feature.

The problem is this: I have a product and I want to earn, let's say, 100€ for each sold product. In this moment this is not possible, because when the user pays, I will have stripe's fees removed from the 100€.

Is there a way to specify: "this is the price that I want to earn, without the fees, the additional fees will be paid by the user"?

Or do I have to increase manually the price and adjust it so that after the fees it will result in 100€?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to do that automatically, you need to manually compute the amount that includes the Stripe fee. The formula to compute that amount is [explained here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/passing-the-stripe-fee-on-to-customers).

However, note that:

- You cannot really know the Stripe fees in advance when using Checkout, since they will change depending on the Payment Method used (for example cards in EU have a different fee than cards in the US). You can learn more about [Stripe pricing here](https://stripe.com/pricing).
- And in some jurisdictions, charging processing fees to your customers is prohibited by law (as explained in the first link I shared).

So instead of customizing the price to each charge, I would recommend to directly set the price to cover your own costs of doing business (including credit card processing fees). For example, charge your customers 102€ for your 100€ product.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I will do!